# How to add a Qt SDK in Qt Creator (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I need to compile my Qt project using a static version of the Qt SDK.

So I have compiled from source a new SDK using these steps:

```
configure (+some options)
make
sudo make -j1 install
```

I think all these steps were successful and I can see the SDK in /usr/local/Trolltech. Then, as indicated [on the reference](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.7/install-mac.html), I have added these lines two my .profile file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

However, when I start Qt Creator, it is not using this new SDK but still using the one that was installed initially. How can I change that and make it use my new SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QtCreator's preferences, there's "Qt4" item (on the left) where you can specify path to your Qt manually.

Regarding PATH variable changes, they'll only be taken into account if you start QtCreator from Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in the options but it asks me to put the path to qmake and I don't know where this file is. Mac OS X won't allow me to browse for it (since I supposed it's a system or hidden file) and I cannot see in /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin from the terminal. Do you know by any chance where this file is? (sorry I'm not very familiar with working with Mac in general)

Comment: While browsing for file, in file open dialog, press Cmd+Shift+g, this'll show up path input dialog. Type /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin in there and hit Return. that's the directory where you'll find qmake executable.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately I cannot see any qmake file in this folder. There are several executables but no qmake. Could it be somewhere else?

Comment: I have it right there. Try executing `find /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1 -name qmake` in Terminal and see if it finds anything.

Comment: @Laurent , qmake is in /usr/bin

Comment: Thanks for your help but it looks like I have a problem with my build as there's no qmake anywhere. The one in /usr/bin is the one installed by Qt Builder and it won't let me build statically. I'm going to mark this answer as accepted anyway because it will help me once I figure out how to build the SDK properly.

Answer (score 0):

To allow Creator to find the Qt installation in PATH, you need to set the PATH variable for GUI apps. Here's some discussion on how to set it in OS X:

https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x

Look for modification to "`environment.plist`".